# can sms manger is used to send multiple SMS (group SMS) ?

Tags: android

I want to send sms by my application. I am using sms manager to sendTextMessage. But when  I Send group SMS, It does not sent sms.

Comment: We need a little bit more information.
What does it mean "it does not send sms" ? Is there an exception, What phone do you use for developing and which android version are
you using? maybe Emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

I can send GroupMessage by using following logic.It uses Application global state.when sending sms, application is paused and control is transfered to the Sms Service.On service return ,it resumes the activity and sending second number.This process continue untill sms to all the number is sent.

I hope this code will help you.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String message;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(etSendmessage.getText())) {
            message = etSendmessage.getText().toString();
            // Toast.makeText(GroupMessaging.this,"Message field is Empty",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            publishProgress(0);

            for (int i = 0; i < contactCount; i++) {

                MyApplication.activityPaused();
                mService.send(groupPhoneNumber[i], message, dataFinal);
                Log.i("name", groupPhoneName[i]);
                publishProgress(i + 1);
                do {

                } while (!(MyApplication.isActivityVisible()));

                Log.i("count", "count" + i);

            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```